# Remove Span From Woocommerce Price Currency Symbol

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to decrease dom element from my
`<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">TL</span>`
Price span is wrapping it

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">459,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span></span>
```

So I don't need it. I want to show price symbol but I don't want to put it inside of a span. It is unnecessary.

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">459,00&nbsp;USD </span>
```

is enough.
Is there any function or action to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using **formatted_woocommerce_price** filter.

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'span_custom_prc', 10, 5 );

function span_custom_prc( $number_format, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator)
{
    return "<span class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'>".$number_format."&nbsp;TL</span>";

    /*  You may use any of these function parameters
     *  $number_format, $price, $decimals, $decimal_seperator and $thousand_seperator 
     *  To show what exactly you desire inside the span tag.
     *  Try ".$price.$decimal_seperator.$decimals" instead of $number_format
    */
}
```

Ref: [Overriding properly WooCommerce function WC_Price() in a clean way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108717/overriding-properly-woocommerce-function-wc-price-in-a-clean-way)

I hope this helps. Selamlar :)

Comment: Selam :) This code added one more Sybmol. Now I need to remove old symbol with span

Comment: I am editing my answer to specify the variable I used ($number_format), please check the new answer. If you still have a problem kindly DM me :)